# Best way to stick adhesive pads to plastic coated with Armor All

Tags: dashboard, plastic

I just bought a dashboard cover to protect the plastic of the dashboard of my Honda CRV from the summer sun.  The instructions for the cover say to stick the included self-adhesive velcro squares on various locations on the dashboard so that the cover will stick to them and not move around.

However, the last time I had the car cleaned, they put a heavy coat of Armor All on the dashboard, and right now nothing will stick to it because of the silicone etc. coating. What's the best way to allow the velcro patches to stick?

Here's what I've thought of:

- Rough up the spots where I want to attach the patches with some finishing pads
- Remove the Armor All in those spots with a solvent like Goo Gone
- Find patches with much stronger adhesive

Ideally, I'd like a solution that neither requires removing all the Armor All from the whole dashboard, nor requires permanently altering the dashboard (like, velcro patches attached with epoxy that can never be removed).

Ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think you could use isopropyl alcohol (IPA) to remove the Armor All and clean the areas of the dash where the adhesive strips need to be done. If that doesn't work, acetone may work, but I'd test it on a very inconspicuous place of the dash to make sure the acetone doesn't dissolve the dash as well. One or the other is going to clean the dash.

I wouldn't sand the areas, because if you want to take the cover off at some point in the future, you'll want to not have caused any damage to the dash.

Comment: A quick search for "how to remove armor all" results in solutions based on window cleaner (Windex ™) and also vinegar, water and a tiny bit of dish detergent.

Comment: Acetone is pretty strong and will melt several plastics and dissolve foams, so definitely do a test before using on a highly visible area. There's likely many other solvents that will remove ArmorAll before resorting to acetone.

Comment: FInally verified this.  The alcohol worked perfectly.  I was able to spot clean where I wanted the velcro to go, and clean the armor all off with that.